# how to set the y-axis properly in solid gauge (highcharts)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I got a problem in Solid Gauge. When i change the width of the browser, the inner element (pane) in solid gauge gets messy. Its getting cutoff. I made the width to 100% but still its not working.

Is there any way to adjust the width of the pane into 100% width? the jsfiddle link is provided in the comments. Please refer that

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/jm8E4/161/

Answer (score 0):

This is because pane size exceeds `100%`. Set it to `100%` and problem will not occur. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jm8E4/162/

Using spacing you could make pane bigger - by decreasing spacing. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jm8E4/163/

API: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.spacing